# In how many ways can five different sweets be split amongst two people if...

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

In how many ways can five different sweets be split amongst two people if one of the sweets is split into two to be shared, and each person gets two of the remaining sweets?

Can someone please help me solve this and show their step by step thought process? Thank you!

Comment: Please show your efforts and where you're stuck to get positive response from the community since this is **not** a do-my-homework-for-me site.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! When you have a minute, please take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and look at [how to format mathematics here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE. Also, I suggest that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for quick reference. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking for a step by step process:

Starting with $5$ sweets, pick one to be split. There are $5$ possible cases.

From the other $4$, pick $2$ at random. Note that because order doesn't matter, there are $5*4C2 = 30$ cases.